# How to draw a vortex with this vectors?

Tags: plotting

i'm learning mathematica. Do you know how to draw vortex with vector like these?
[image]

Moreover I would like a picture like this:

[image]
Without axes or other indication
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen `VectorPlot[]`?

Comment: Also `ListVectorPlot`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListVectorPlot[
Table[{y/(x^2 + y^2 + 2), -(x/(x^2 + y^2 + 2))}, {x, -3, 3, 
0.3}, {y, -3, 3, 0.3}], PlotTheme -> "Minimal"]
```

[image]